# Sort select fields listed in table rows based on values in the combo boxes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the DataTables plugin to sort a basic html table. One of the columns in the table contains a select box on each row that contain statuses pertinent to the application.

Currently, I'm just using the basic code to initialize the DataTable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tacticInstancesTable').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[4, "desc"]]
    });
});
```

Is it possible to modify this code so I can sort by values selected in the combo boxes? The solution has been difficult to find because most search results provide answers on how to sort using a combo box - whereas I want to sort the combo boxes themselves.

[image: Screenshot of column to sort]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables.Net is an extensive plugin and covers most of the resources you need. 
You need to use `dom-select`

```
{ "sSortDataType": "dom-select" }
```

Need full HTML and table structure for correct answer, but this is how you implement sorting feature for something like what you want (with `sSortDataType: "dom-select"`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-text" },
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "numeric" },
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-select" },
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Here's your answer: http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

### Update

**JS fiddle Sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZdP84/4/

Comment: Thank you for the link to documentation. In the example listed there is a function:
`/* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */`

Is that a necessary addition too, or is simply declaring the column type enough?

Comment: Yes, you need to create the function.

Comment: Updated answer with JSFIDDLE sample.